# How to compare all columns of 2 rows from the same table (Snowflake)?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table stored in Snowflake consisting of employee information. Each employee has a unique ID, and there are 2 rows for each unique ID. Row1 for a unique ID represents new/current personal details, row2 represents details from an old system. There are around 70 columns
(e.g. title, name, date of birth, address, postcode, email etc...) and there are lots of employees.

I need to compare all columns between the two rows for each employee, and output a single row with all column names stating false/0 if the rows in that column were the same, and outputting true/1 if they were different. Except for ID column (leaving as a primary key).

For example:

MyTable:

| ID | FIRSTNAME | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Jack | 20000 |
| 123 | Jack | 25000 |

Output:

| ID | FIRSTNAME | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 0 | 1 |

I have come up with a solution but it requires me to manually enter every column name, I'm sure there is a better way. (If the SQL gets overly complex I can also use Python)

My Solution:

```
SELECT 
CURRENT.ID
, CASE WHEN CURRENT.FIRSTNAME = PREVIOUS.FIRSTNAME THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE END AS FIRSTNAME
-- ETC... FOR ALL COLUMNS 
FROM MYTABLE CURRENT
INNER JOIN MYTABLE PREVIOUS ON (CURRENT.ID = PREVIOUS.ID)
WHERE CURRENT.VERSION = 'CURRENT' AND PREVIOUS.VERSION = 'PREVIOUS'
```

Comment: you can use `LAG(col_name) OVER (partitionby ID order by ID)` as well. But what exactly you are looking for ? If you create a SQL, you have to mention all column names. You can put them in XL and create a formula to create a script - no need to type

Comment: If you can do it efficiently by python - I'd do it with python. "I'm sure there is a better way"  ( (in SQL) isn't true. You would need to resort to some query gymnastics to produce "dynamic sql " in an effort to avoid typing in the column names. or use Excel as suggested above - it's a hack but it works. (nb: you still need all the columns names even for this)

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the select statement in your solution using metadata tables.

Comment: So I know I can generate the column nanes from metadata, but that means I would need to generate a dynamic SQL script to loop through each column. Any idea how I can do this ?